# Why does Wordpress creates image thumbnails bigger (in file size) than the original?

Tags: wordpress, size, thumbnails

I've been looking around a correct answer for this question, but I couldn't find one.

Here is an example of three (3) images / files that I uploaded to Wordpress. As you can see, some of the thumbnails are smaller in dimensions, but larger in file size. I read that maybe it has something to do with the bit depth of the image. But anyway, it does not make sense to me. Wouldn't be more logical that Wordpress verify the size, make a copy of the original and rename it before creating bigger/scaled versions of it?

I tried this with and without plugins/themes installed. The only difference is that having them activated wordpress would create more thumbnails, but the issue exists in both ways. And using plugins to prevent image sizes won't solve the problem either. It seems its a core Wordpress problem, that it must be solved.

Does anyone have a solution, snippet, workaround, plugin, or advice for this?

Thank you!!!

[image]